# Undo wrong sorting after missing leading zeros

Tags: algorithm, mapping, leading-zero

Here you have a little riddle for anyone who wants to spend some time on it:

I have around 200 files that got badly sorted and renamed due to the lack of leading zeros. I have to undo this sorting, and assign the original values again, so that I have an order like this:

```
current file name                original

TimePoint1            ->         TimePoint1
TimePoint2            ->         TimePoint10
TimePoint3            ->         TimePoint100
TimePoint4            ->         TimePoint101
TimePoint5            ->         TimePoint102
                     ...
TimePoint250          ->         TimePoint250
```

I will work on an answer, but I didn't want to miss any of the elegant solutions you might provide.

Thanks and have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is simply alphabetical order. So the easiest way to un-do this sorting will be to use this order again. I am not sure which language you want to use so here is an example in ruby:

```
a = []
(1..250).each{|t| a << t.to_s} # note that I am adding the *string* representation
a.sort!
(0...250).each do |i|
  File.rename("TimePoint#{a[i]}", "TimePoint#{i + 1}")
end
```

Comment: Of course... goes to think I was thinking on the wrong track :D